# Could not connect to a host in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to import a CSV data file in my MongoDB collection transaction which I created in the Mongo Db Atlas.

mongoimport --uri "mongodb+srv://username:password@reportingdata-n8b3j.mongodb.net/ecommerce?retryWrites=true&w=majority" --collection transactions --drop --type csv --headerline --file data.csv

2021-04-25T23:57:49.742+0200    WARNING: ignoring unsupported URI parameter 'retrywrites'
2021-04-25T23:57:50.397+0200    Failed: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.
2021-04-25T23:57:50.397+0200    imported 0 documents

Comment: "Authentication failed" is rather specific.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authentication failure while trying to save to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb)